# Integration and Absolute Values

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, integrating-factor, reduction-of-order-ode

I am doing a Reduction of Order problem that requires an Integrating Factor.  I understand how to do it [almost] perfectly fine.  I do not understand a couple steps in the integration processes.

$$xy''+y'=0;  y_1=ln(x)$$
The answer is $y_2=1$.  Keep in mind this ISN'T an IVP nor is any interval of validity implied or given.

I get to the integrating factor computed by...

$$μ(x)=e^{\int\frac{(2+ln(x))dx}{xln(x)}}$$
$$=e^{ln(ln^2(x))}・e^{ln|x|}$$
$$=|x|ln^2(x)$$

This $μ(x)$ causes trouble with one of the final integrals...
$$\int du=C_1\int\frac{dx}{|x|ln^2(x)}$$

This leads me to my question.  Why do so many sources (such as [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20(2%2Bln(x))%2F(xln(x)))) in the case of my $μ(x)$) drop the abs(...) from the end result of the integral?  I distinctly recall being taught in Calculus classes to keep the abs(...) when it applies.

Linked [here](http://oi67.tinypic.com/28lrkat.jpg) is my overall work until the point where I am stuck.

Comment: You shouldn't worry too much about the absolute value. Note that your initial solution $y_1(x) = \ln x$ is defined only on $(0,\infty)$ so anyway all this integrals you do are on the domain $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks levap.  I got to thinking as well that x≠0 because it is in the denominator also, implying I:  (-∞,0) or (0,∞)... and obviously (-∞,0) won't work without keeping abs(...) at a few key points in the problem.  Again, I guess it's just another case of it being easier to drop the abs(...).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**
when you write $\ln^2 (x) $, it means that $x>0$ so $|x|=x $.